# How do I sync a css value with a form input with angularJS?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I have a colour selector input and I want to set the background-color to the value of the input on load, and whenever it is changed. How can I achieve this with angularJS? I can set it on load with ng-style but it doesn't update when the value changes

```
<input type="text" ng-style="setColour(colour)" class="pickerInput" ng-model="colour" />
```

and:

```
$scope.setColour = function (colour) {
    return { 'background-color': colour }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like:

```
$scope.setColour = function () {
    return { background-color: +"'"+ $scope.colour+"'" }
};
```

Sorry but it's a little tricky to test it myself.

**Update**

I changed my reply because of the syntax of the reference

[http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngStyle](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angStyle)

```
ng-click="myStyle={color:'red'}"
```

Comment: I think this doesn't work because ng-style is only evaluated at the start and not refreshed

Comment: I had luck with just style="background-color: {{colour}};". Is there any reason not to do it this way?

Comment: do console.log(colour) in the controller it should be undefined with my code and if you use your code the model in not update imo all in all it's better to set up a working plunker or like that